# Sorting specific columns of a dataframe by their names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

`df` is a test dataframe and I need to sort the last three columns in ascending order (without hardcoding the order).

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            Z = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            Y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            C = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
            B = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Desired output:

```
> df
  X Z Y A B C
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

I'm aware of the `order()` function but I can't seem to find the right way to implement it to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base `R`, a selection on the first columns then sort the last 3 names :

```
df[, c(names(df)[1:(ncol(df)-3)], sort(names(df)[ncol(df)-2:0]))]
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can also use `head` and `tail` as an alternative `df[,c(head(names(df),-3),sort(tail(names(df),3))) ]`

Comment: @maydin good alternative. I prefer to keep `base` solution without `utils` package.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:**

Base R:

```
cbind(df[1:3],df[4:6][,order(colnames(df[4:6]))])
```

**First answer:**

We could use `relocate` from `dplyr`:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/relocate.html

It is configured to arrange columns:

Here we  relocate by the index.
We take last (index = 6) and put it before (position 5, which is C)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  relocate(6, .before = 5)
```

An alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(order(colnames(df))) %>% 
  relocate(4:6, .before = 1)
```

```
X Z Y A B C
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Could you explain what exactly (.before = 5) does?

Answer (score 1):

We want to reorder the columns based on the column names, so if we use `names(df)` as the argument to order, we can reorder the data frame as follows.

The complicating factor is that `order()` returns a vector of numbers, so if we want to reorder only a subset of the column names, we'll need an approach that retains the original sort order for the first three columns.

We accomplish this by creating a vector of the first 3 column names, the sorted remaining column names using a function that returns the values rather than locations in the vector, and then use this with the `[` form of the extract operator.

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 Z = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 Y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 C = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 B = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

df[,c(names(df[1:3]),sort(names(df[4:6])))]
```

...and the output:

```
> df[,c(names(df[1:3]),sort(names(df[4:6])))]
  X Z Y A B C
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Comment: The desired order of the columns is (X,Z,Y,A,B,C) and not (A,B,C,X,Y,Z). The order and position of the first three columns should remain unchanged.

Comment: @AbhishekChowdhury - thanks. need more coffee this morning. Updated answer has the output you expected. The challenge with using `order()` is that it returns index numbers instead of the names.

Comment: Dear Mr. Greski, it's always a pleasure to meet you here.

Answer (score 1):

```r
to_order <- seq(ncol(df)) > ncol(df) - 3

df[order(to_order*order(names(df)))]
#>   X Z Y A B C
#> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
#> 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
#> 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
#> 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
#> 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>